# Why I can not reach csv file after 10 min AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a scheduled job and run it periodically in AWS Lambda. I can read file until schedule job running execution after 10 minute. However, I can not reach to file after 10 min.

Error log is:

> with open('/tmp/out.csv', "rb") as f:
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/out.csv'

In addition: I can not show this file on editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/tmp` directory in AWS Lambda is temporary storage. Files stored there by your Lambda function are available for at least the duration of that same Lambda function invocation.

After a given Lambda invocation has completed, the AWS Lambda service may re-use the same environment for a new function invocation (the so-called "warm start") in which case the `/tmp` contents will still be there.

However, Lambda doesn't guarantee this. Lambda will, at some point, dispose of the entire runtime environment and your next Lambda invocation will start with a brand new environment (the so-called "cold start").

So, treat `/tmp` as temporary. You can use it to attempt to cache files for the next Lambda function invocation but don't rely on that.